# row().data to retrieve a specific column row using datatables.net plug-in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datatable

EDIT: Deleted my YouTube Video, here is **simple solution**:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_btn', function() {
  var rowData = $('#example').DataTable().row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
});
```

**"Working Code":**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).on('click','.edit_btn',function (){
      var id = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0];
        var edit_id = $('#example').DataTable().row( id ).data();
        var edit_id = edit_id[0];
    $.ajax({
         url: 'index.php',
          datatype: "json",
      data: { edit_id : edit_id },
      async: false,
        success: function(result) {
              //alert(edit_id);
                  $("#edit_id").val(edit_id);
        } //success func
    }); //ajax
}); //end ready
</script>
```

**What I tried**
I tried many things as in the youTube video. I could not get the original example to work on the link.

Should I use Jquery like this??
 `var last_name = $('#example').DataTable().row( last_name ).data();`

Or php like this?
`$('#editLastName').val( <?php echo $row['first_name']; ?> );`

Or something within the ajax file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could try is to get the parent tr element, although I'm not sure if that's the best approach.

Simplified:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_btn', function() {
  var rowData = $('#example').DataTable().row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
});
```

Basically you get the parent tr from the button element you click on and get the data from that row.

What I also noticed, your data-id from the button seems messed up. It looks like this: `data-id='s-"0"'`. I'm not sure how you generate this, but in case you fix that and it looks like `data-id="0"` you can select rows with `$('#example').DataTable().row($(this).data('id')).data();`.

As you can see, there are quite a few possibilities here.

Comment: `columnDefs: [
      {  targets: -1,
         render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
            return '<button type="submit" class="delete_btn btn btn-danger btn-md active" id=n-"' + meta.row + '" value="delete" style="margin-right: 10px"/>  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>  </button> <button type="submit"  class="edit_btn btn btn-success btn-md active" data-id=s-"' + meta.row + '"  id=s-"' + meta.row + '" value="edit" name="edit_btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editForm">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>  </a>';
         }
      }
    ]`

Comment: ....is how my edit button was produced. maybe I should edit that in within the topic. I will try to find a link supporting why the "s" is there. i think its a datatables thing. i will try your method now.

Comment: Instead of `data-id=s-"' + meta.row + '"` you want `data-id="' + meta.row + '"` there.

Comment: ok so basically delete the 's'. i deleted it and the code still worked. your method did alert the row properly. now i probably just need to rowData[1] for the first name and rowData[2] for the last name.